# Trying to make a bot to connect on discord with Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, bots

Trying to make a bot to connect on discord with Selenium Python: I've been trying to make a bot to connect to my discord.

Imports needed are listed below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
```

The following code is my script - defining DiscordBot:

```
class DiscordBot:

def __init__(self, email, password):
    self.email = email
    self.password = password
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def closeBrowser(self):
    self.driver.close()      

def login(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https://discordapp.com/login")
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    email = browser.find_element("register-email")
    email.send_keys("discordbot@icloud.com")
    password = browser.find_element("register-password")
    password.send_keys("my password")
    browser.find_element_by_name("login").click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

However, my problem it when the above code runs, it produces the following error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: 
Message: unknown variant `register-email`, expected one of `css selector`, `link text`,
`partial link text`, `tag name`, `xpath` at line 1 column 26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use CSS [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selectors to target the required elements.

```
email = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[type=email]")
password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[type=password]")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[type=submit]").click()
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Selenium Discord Login with Python:

I Tried all the above code and It was not working for me so after some hustle, Here is the Discord Selenium Python Automation Code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://discord.com/login")
time.sleep(6)

username_input = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
username_input.send_keys("enter-your-username-here")


password_input = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password_input.send_keys("Enter-your-password-here")


login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/button[2]')
login_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to define `browser` (`Firefox` instance) as you already has `driver` (another `Firefox` instance)
2. You need to pass *type of selector* as first argument to `find_element`, e.g.

   ```
   email = driver.find_element("name", "register-email")
   email = driver.find_element(value="register-email") # if your selector type is "id" (default type)
   ```

Comment: now when I do 
email = driver.find_element(id="register-email")
this pop up
TypeError: find_element() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Comment: @bebe And any reason why you did that? Where in my code did you find `id="register-email"`?